# MATLAB checking if part of a matrix is within x % of the first column

Tags: matlab, matrix, percentage

I've got a quick question about matrices in MATLAB.

Given a 3x4 matrix, how would you check if everything on the right side of the first column is within 80% of the first column? I can't really seem to come up with anything.

Example:

```
Temperature = [60 59 55 50; 60 48 30 46; 60 45 37 47]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
relTemp = bsxfun(@rdivide,Temperature(:,2:end),Temperature(:,1));

%# be within +/- 80% of first column
isWithin80Perc = all(relTemp > 0.2 & relTemp < 1.8,2);
```